# Laravel Nova Number Format

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm trying to format an integer in Laravel Nova but nothing seems to work.

I have tried the following:

```
Currency::make('Price', 'price')
        ->displayUsing(function($value) {
             return number_format($value, ',');
        })
        ->hideFromDetail(),

Currency::make('Price', 'price')
        ->format('%.2n')
        ->hideFromDetail(),
```

It also doesn't work if I utilise the Number field.

The result is always an unformatted number like **49000000000** when it should be **49,000,000,000**

What am I missing?

Comment: View this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57551781/thousand-separator-in-forms/57606820#57606820

Answer (score 2):

Try this, maybe help you:

```
Text::make('Price', 'price', function () {
    return !is_null($this->price) ? number_format($this->price, 2, '.', ',') : 0;
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is using Accessors and mutators inside your Product modal instead.

Assume you have a Product modal with a price attribute

```
public function price(): Attribute
{
  return Attribute::make(
      get: fn ($value) => number_format($value, 2, '.', ','),
      set: fn ($value) => str_replace(',', '', $value),
  );
}
```

This will always format the price after it get's the value. And when you save the price it will replace the ',' and just saves the plain number.

In Nova

```
Number::make('Price', 'price')->min(0),
```

[Link to documentation - Laravel 9.+](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)